# ACL BUG when using stream_context_create losses permission in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, acl, google-cloud-storage

Good day,

Im wondering if you could help me on the tiny bug??? i've encountered. I cannot make the file "coolguy" publicly available not matter what I do. There is no checkbox in the webconsole.

To create the file, i used the following code, but i think there is something wrong with the acl

```
$options = [
'gs' => [
'Content-Type' => $type,
'acl'=> 'public-read'

 ],
];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);

copy($oldpath, $new_full_path , $ctx);
```

im using the guide here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/public_access?hl=pl and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload?hl=pl

Comment: You can use "Storage Browser" in https://console.developers.google.com to verify/change permission.

Comment: Storage Browser doesnt show checkbox and permission is also disabled. However font out that is was set to public by directly going to the file's endpoint.